# In app linked2sd i convert download mngr into usser app from system app, then it start my phone to get error

Tags: 5.1-lollipop

My phone k7, always unfortunately process android.process.media has stopped, and my keyboard aosp to. Pls help

Answer (score 2):

Try to convert all your Google apps to user app and you will end up with an endless stream of "unfortunately...... has stopped" . That's to tell you that some apps won't run as user app. Download manager is one of such apps. Get it back into the system before you start having real problems with your browser and play store